# Cannot run chmod on NTFS-3G file system. How to enable it?

Tags: permissions, 22.04, fstab, ntfs

My Ubuntu operating system have both permissions & acl features enabled for NTFS-3G when it is mounted by fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
PARTUUID=86b1e9b5-0ff0-4566-a1a5-6034817df59c  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077  0  0
UUID=ed5a8772-679d-483e-9192-2340f5160635  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
/swapfile none swap defaults 0 0
UUID=1D5F100E68B50F72  /home/peng  ntfs-3g  defaults,permissions,acl,nls=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names  0  0
```

But when I try to chmod a dummy file's permission to 700, nothing changed:

```
$ chmod 700 dummy 
$ ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 peng peng 0 Jul  9 23:08 dummy
$ ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 peng peng 0 Jul  9 23:08 dummy
```

Why are the `permissions,acl` option being ignored? And how to truly enable them?

**UPDATE 1**: it turns out that the driver for the mount is still using `fuseblock` which should be long obsolete:

```
$ mount | grep sda
/dev/sda1 on /home/shared type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodatasum,nodatacow,ssd,space_cache=v2,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
/dev/sda2 on /home/peng type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

This is weird as NTFS-3G should already be preferred in kernel 5.17:

```
$ uname -r
5.17.15-76051715-generic
```

**UPDATE 2**: the latest document explained that uid & gid probably shouldn't exist in fstab, so I removed them:

```
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
PARTUUID=86b1e9b5-0ff0-4566-a1a5-6034817df59c  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077  0  0
UUID=ed5a8772-679d-483e-9192-2340f5160635  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
/swapfile none swap defaults 0 0
UUID=1D5F100E68B50F72  /home/peng  ntfs-3g  permissions,nls=utf8,windows_names  0  0
```

But after rebooting, the mount option still looks sketchy and inconsistent:

```
$ mount  | grep sda
/dev/sda1 on /home/shared type btrfs (rw,noatime,nodatasum,nodatacow,ssd,space_cache=v2,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
/dev/sda2 on /home/peng type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Regardless, I can now chmod & chown most files, but I still don't know if this is the ideal configuration

Comment: Please, make sure `ntfs-3g` is installed first ... then run `sudo modprobe -r ntfs3`  ... then **remount** your NTFS partition and see if it works.

Comment: @Raffa yes they are all done, and it still doesn't work

Comment: But you are right it is using fuseblock, I've updated my question

Comment: Is it Ubuntu or POP_OS?

Comment: POP_OS, but theoretically Ubuntu should have the same problem as its kernel is older

Comment: Pop!_OS is not supported here.  You can ask about Pop!_OS on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com). | https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: OK, but I discovered the solution (see my answer) which should be applicable to Ubuntu, feel free to decide if it should be left here

Comment: Does not matter; The rules are: only official Ubuntu is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out many best-practice configuration online after the latest NTFS-3G have introduced the POSIX permission, which should be configured according to this table:

| File access checks | Conditions |
| --- | --- |
| No permission checks | No **uid**, **gid**, **fmask**, **dmask**, **umask** or **permissions** or **acl** option, and no user mapping file found |
| Same ownership (uid, gid) and permissions for all files and directories (restricted by fmask, dmask and umask) | **uid** or **gid** or **fmask** or **dmask** or **umask** defined, and no user mapping file found |
| Standard permission checks, according to ownership and mode, and POSIX ACLs not used (uid, gid, fmask dmask and umask ignored) | - No **uid** or **gid** or **fmask** or **dmask** or **umask** or **acl** defined, **permissions** defined, and no user mapping file found **OR** - POSIX ACLs not selected at compile-time, and user mapping file found **OR** - POSIX ACLs selected at compile-time, **permissions** defined, and user mapping file found |
| Permissions according to ownership, mode and POSIX ACLs (uid, gid, fmask, dmask and umask ignored) | POSIX ACLs selected at compile-time, No **permissions**, and acl defined **OR** POSIX ACLs selected at compile-time, No **permissions**, and user mapping file found |

(source: https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/wiki/File-Ownership-and-Permissions)

As a result, all options that involves `uid` and `gid` are strictly forbidden. In the end this is the fstab I'm using:

```
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
...
UUID=1D5F100E68B50F72  /home/peng  ntfs-3g  permissions,nls=utf8  0  0

$ mount  | grep sda
/dev/sda2 on /home/peng type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

So far, it appears to be working as intended.

Unfortunately, The ACL control still seems to be VERY EXPERIMENTAL and could only be used later, when the compile-time option is permanently enabled